Composition linear transformations
Let $\alpha=\{(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$ and $\beta=\{(1,3),(1,4)\}$ be basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, respectively.
Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a linear transformation such that
$$[T]^{\alpha}_{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 11 & 5 \\ -1 & -8 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $S\colon\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ another linear transformation with
$$S(x,y)=(2x,3x+y)$$
I have to find $[S\circ T]_{\beta}^{\alpha}$.
I followed the following steps: since
$$S(1,3)=(2,6),\qquad S(1,4)=(2,7)$$
then
$$[S]_{\beta}^{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\ 6 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$$
Hence
$$[S\circ T]_{\beta}^{\alpha}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\ 6 & 7 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 11 & 5 \\ -1 & -8 & -3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 
4 & 6 & 4 \\ 11 & 10 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$$
However, if I tried to evaluate $(S\circ T)(2,1,1)=S(T(2,1,1))$ in two different ways and I believe something is wrong:
First method: I know that
$$T(2,1,1)=\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 11 & 5 \\ -1 & -8 & -3 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 22 \\ -13 \end{bmatrix}$$
so,
$$S(T(2,1,1))=S(22,-13)=(2\cdot22,3\cdot22-13)=(44,53)$$
Second method: using the matrix:
$$S(T(2,1,1))=\begin{bmatrix} 
4 & 6 & 4 \\ 11 & 10 & 9 \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} 22 \\ -13 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 18 \\ 41 \end{bmatrix}$$
So: what is right and what is wrong?

If $\alpha = {u,v,w}$ in the same order you've written it then $(2,1,1)=u+w$ which is $(1,0,1)$ with respect to $\alpha$.

Is even matrix multiplication possible in your second method?

Use $[S]_{\beta}^{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \ 6 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$

@mvfs314 Also I think  $[T]^{\alpha}{\beta}$ should be $[T]^{\beta}{\alpha}$ and $[S\circ T]{\beta}^{\alpha}$ should be $[S\circ T]{\alpha}^{\beta}$.

Then $[S\circ T]{\alpha}^{\beta}=[S]{\beta}^{\beta}[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta}$
